# How is Aika related to Mahiro in zetsuten no tempest?

Tags: zetsuen-no-tempest

I have watched the anime Zetsuten no Tempest (Blast of Tempest) recently and I am confused about the relationship between Aika and Mahiro.

From the anime it appears that Mahiro was the son of a rich and influential man and at some point he met with Aika who was to become his new sister.

What I don't understand is: was Aika an orphan child who was adopted by Mahiro's family or did his father remarry or something similar? Also, neither Mahiro nor Aika's parents are ever shown in the anime, are they dead? If so, is there any information concerning their deaths?

I have heard that there's also a Manga, so it might be that the anime is missing some information.

Answer (score 2):

According to the wikia, Aika is Mahiro's step-sister through her mother's remarriage to Mahiro's father and both their parents were found dead along with Aika.

http://zetsuennotempest.wikia.com/wiki/Aika_Fuwa

Comment: Could you add a link to the page on the Wikia that says this?